# Vector Formulation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, systems-of-equations

In the "Systems of Differential Equations" section of my Differential Equations and Linear Algebra class, I've gotten to a section called "Vector Formulation". It has seemed simple enough until I got to a question shown below:

> Let $\,A\left(t\right)\,$ be an $\,n\times n\,$ matrix function. 
>   Prove that the set of all solutions $\,x\,$ to the system:
>   $$x'(t) = A\left(t\right)\,x\left(t\right)$$
>   is a subspace of $\,V_n\left(I\right)\,$ (the set of all column $\,n$-vector functions on $\,I\,$)

I'm just hoping someone could give me a starting direction here. I know that to prove something is a subspace you have to show closure under addition and scalar multiplication and that it contains the zero vector, but I can't figure out how to begin applying it here. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: What is $\,I\,$?

Comment: Show that if $x_1,x_2$ are solutions then so is $x_1+x_2$. Show that if $x$ is a solution, then so is $\lambda x$, where $\lambda$ is a scalar.

Comment: Yeah I just need to know how to show that with Vn(I)